# Clasura where em campo tipo json no (Laravel + Eloquent)

Tags: sql, json, laravel, laravel-eloquent

O problema é o Seguinte, tenho que trazer de um select as permissões que um perfil tem, só que as permissões estão em um campo json, e por se tratar de várias permissões temos uma coleção de dados, preciso fazer isso dentro de um middleware:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $rotaSolicitada){

    try{
        $usuario = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        return response()->json(['error'=> true, 'mensagem'=> 'Não foi possível autenticar no sistema', 'data'=> null], 500);
    }

    $permissao = Perfil::with('usuario')
                    ->where('id', $usuario->id)
                    ->where('recursos->rota', 'reserva')
                    ->get();

    //aqui é só para exibir o retorno (teste)   
    dump($permissao);
    return response()->json($permissao);



    $recursoSolicitado = str_replace( '@','',strstr($request->route()->getActionName(), '@'));


    return $next($request);
}
```

o meu banco de dados está assim:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('perfis', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('descricao', 45);
        $table->json('recursos')->nullable();
        $table->char('status',1);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Retorno do select feito direto no banco (select * from perfils)
[image: select da table]

Formato do Json da coluna recursos que eu quero buscar:

```
[{
"rota": "reserva",
"sref": "oQueFazer",
"ordem": "1",
"recursos": ["index", "show"],
"descricao": "Reservar",
"controller": "ReservasController"
}, {
    "rota": "reserva",
    "sref": "oQueFazer",
    "ordem": "2",
    "recursos": ["index", "show"],
    "descricao": "Reservas",
    "controller": "ReservasController"
}, {
    "rota": "usuario",
    "sref": "oQueFazer",
    "ordem": "3",
    "recursos": ["index", "show"],
    "descricao": "Usuários",
    "controller": "UsuariosController"
}, {
    "rota": "feriado",
    "sref": "oQueFazer",
    "ordem": "4",
    "recursos": ["index", "show"],
    "descricao": "Feriados",
    "controller": "FeriadosController"
}, {
    "rota": "sala",
    "sref": "home.sala",
    "ordem": "5",
    "recursos": ["index", "show"],
    "descricao": "Salas",
    "controller": "SalasController"
}]
```

Em resumo, eu quero fazer um `where`nesse campo `json`, que tem o nome de `recursos`. Gostaria de exibir todos os `recursos` do `json` onde a `rota = 'reservas`.

Tentei assim e não deu certo:

```
 $permissao = Perfil::with('usuario')
                    ->where('id', $usuario->id)
                    ->where('recursos->rota', 'reserva')
                    ->get();
```

Comment: Dá algum erro???

Comment: Não, ele retorna fazio `[ ]` é como se o `->where('recursos->rota', 'reserva')` estivesse com parâmetros errado!

Comment: Qual é a versão do banco, fazendo favor porque era pra dar certo.

Comment: Versão do banco é 5.7.14 (acredito que o que está me atrapalhando é que no meu field Json que se chama recursos no banco de dados, lá eu não tenho uma só informação de Json, eu tenho um conjunto de Json.) Não tenho tanto conhecimento técnico, mas acredito que seja isso, e não sei como solucionar...

Comment: Amigo tem um chave a mais se observou isso? tipo links um array depois recursos->rota? se observou?

Comment: É justamente dela que eu to falando, eu não tenho uma linha de json, tenho um conjunto, tenho que verificar cada json por cada linha da consulta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67352/discussion-between-milrak-pereira-pessoa-and-virgilio-novic).

Comment: @VirgilioNovic quando estiver por aqui, avisa.

Comment: Oikkkkkkkkkkkkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por uma explicação do site a lógica seria com [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html)

```
mysql> SET @j = '{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": {"d": 4}}';
mysql> SET @j2 = '1';
mysql> SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(@j, @j2, '$.a');
+-------------------------------+
| JSON_CONTAINS(@j, @j2, '$.a') |
+-------------------------------+
|                             1 |
+-------------------------------+
```

e nesse outro link sobre [JSON Paths](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/), explica como trabalhar com `wildcard (*)` sendo que um `array` para uma determinada busca seria `$.[*]` e o nome do campo. [O retorno do JSON_CONTAINS pode ser 1 ou 0 se a consulta está contida no documento `JSON` ou `NULL` se os argumentos forem `null` ou se a seção do documento `JSON` não for identificado.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains)

Um exemplo no seu código acredito que seja:

```
$permissao = Perfil::with('usuario')
                ->where('id', $usuario->id)
                ->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(recursos, "reserva", $.[*]rota)=1')
                ->get();
```

- [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html)
- [12.16.3 Functions That Search JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains)

Complementando a resposta, segue a solução:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(recursos, '$[0].recursos') permite from perfis
WHERE
JSON_CONTAINS(recursos, '{"controller": "FeriadosController"}');
```